I2C on OLED using 27MHz FPGA and 24MHz Logic Analyzer
I have a tang-nano-9k which has a 27MHz system clock.
The only logic analyzer I have is a generic 24MHz copycat.
I want to implement I2C between the FPGA and a SSD1306 OLED display.
My concern is that debugging via the logic analyzer will not work very well, as it is not operating at the correct frequency, or even a multiple.
The only thought I have had is to divide the clock and generate signals out of the FPGA at 12MHz, then at least sigrok would be easier to read.
Anyway - open to ideas! How would this forum proceed?

The 27 MHz system clock or 24 MHz logic analyzer are irrelevant.
The I2C bus can operate as slowly as you want, and maximum speed for the SSD1306 is 400 kHz anyway, well within reach of the 24 MHz logic analyzer.
Generally you might want to sample at 8 MHz or higher to make sure the timings are correct when verifying the 400 kHz bus integrity and FPGA implementation, but slower speeds can be used for occasional debugging and for slower bus speeds, 2 MHz should be enough for 100 kHz bus.

My main concern is with using the 24MHz LA to read a 27MHz clock

As in: will this make life difficult when it comes to debugging? And if so - should I divide the 27MHz clock before routing any signals to the LA

@K_T You can't analyze the 27 MHz clock with a LA that samples at 24 MHz. And you also have no need to do so when communicating I2C. Why do you think you need to analyze the 27 MHz clock, or a divided down version of it, what purpose it will serve? Of course you can divide it down and measure it, but that has nothing to do with I2C, unless you explain how it would relate.

I see what you mean - I think I mentioned I2C here more as context than as a focal point. Sorry - l suppose the question is misleading

@K_T OK, but the "system clock" being 27 MHz is still irrelevant, as that's just the reference clock fed to the FPGA. The FPGA has a PLL and can run at several hundred MHz, and the high speed lane interfaces allow up to a couple of gigabits per second. The question seemed to be only about debugging I2C.
